# Glassfish throws MessageException if I use Response.ResponseBuilder

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

My program used to work, but after I have updated NetBeans and Glassfish it stated to throw:
**com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.LinkedList, and Java type class java.util.LinkedList, and MIME media type application/json was not found**

I have spend several days already googling a solution but nothing works. So I have created a small proof of concept code:

```
@Path("frend")
@Stateless
public class MyFrend
{
    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    public MyFrend(){}

    // Throws: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class java.util.LinkedList, and Java type class java.util.LinkedList, and MIME media type application/json was not found

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getAssets()
    {
        List<Frend> frends = new LinkedList<Frend>();
        frends.add( new Frend() );
        frends.add( new Frend() );

        Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok( frends, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE );

        Response r = rb.build();
        return r;
    }
}
```

If I replace return type "Response" with "List" it works but wraps the list into a root element, which breaks the compatibility with existing clients. Here is the code:

```
@Path("ok")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Frend> getAssetsOk()
{
    List<Frend> frends = new LinkedList<Frend>();
    frends.add( new Frend() );
    frends.add( new Frend() );
    return frends;
}
```

It produces: {"**frend**":[{"id":"0","name":"Bob"},{"id":"0","name":"Bob"}]}

While I need: [{"id":"0","name":"Bob"},{"id":"0","name":"Bob"}]

Just in case here is my "Frend" class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="frend")
public class Frend
{
  public int id;
  public String name = "Bob";
}
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot,

--Sergey

Comment: Try adding genson library to your classpath, it would enable json support

Comment: @eugen If I go to Project Properties/Libraries/Global Libraries I don't see the "genson" library there. Should I download it from http://code.google.com/p/genson/ and add manually?

Comment: if you use maven you just need to add a new dependency to genson, otherwise yes you have to download it on the site and then add it to your classpath

Comment: @eugen I have added downloaded genson-0.94.jar and added it to the library. Now I have a new message: WARNING: WEB9052: Unable to load class com.owlike.genson.ext.jersey.GensonJsonConverter, reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.owlike.genson.ext.jersey.GensonJsonConverter

And the old error: SEVERE: A message body writer ...
SEVERE: The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json ->  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem that caused the exception I had to wrap the entity in GenericEntity class:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAssets()
{
    LinkedList<Frend> frends = new LinkedList<Frend>();
    frends.add( new Frend() );
    frends.add( new Frend() );

    GenericEntity<LinkedList<Frend>> entity = new GenericEntity<LinkedList<Frend>>(frends) {};

    Response.ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok( entity, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE );
    Response r = rb.build();
    return r;
}
```

But then I have got the same problem as when I have just returned LinkedList:
It produces:

{"**frend**":[{"id":"0","name":"Bob"},{"id":"0","name":"Bob"}]}

While I need:

[{"id":"0","name":"Bob"},{"id":"0","name":"Bob"}]

Comment: Tnx for this answer! Was trying for couple of hours.